# How to mount Gluster volume in a systemd-nspawn container?

Tags: systemd, containers, glusterfs, fuse

I am trying to mount a Gluster volume within a systemd-nspawn container.
I found two methods to do it from the official Github repo, but I have questions about both methods' security.

1. The `CAP_MKNOD` + `DeviceAllow=/dev/fuse rwm` + `mknod /dev/fuse c 10 229` from https://github.com/systemd/systemd/issues/6553#issuecomment-350167906. But I can only make it work using a privileged container, am I doing it wrong, or it really only works in a privileged container?

   ```ini
   # /etc/systemd/nspawn/apps.nspawn
   [Exec]
   NotifyReady=yes
   PrivateUsers=no
   ```
2. The `/dev/fuse` bind mount method from https://github.com/systemd/systemd/issues/7669#issuecomment-352388204. It works in an unprivileged container, but the author stated that this method has security implications. I don't know what it means, is it worse than method 1?

   ```ini
   # /etc/systemd/nspawn/apps.nspawn
   [Files]
   Bind=/dev/fuse
   ```